# Undefined offset: 0 LARAVEL 8

Tags: laravel

ErrorException
Undefined offset: 0

I am having this error and have being trying to resolve it without any solution. I need help please? Thanks

Below is my controller

```
public function rts(Request $request) {

     $server = config('services.rsa.live_server');
    $dbName = config('services.rsa.live_db');
    $uid = config('services.rsa.live_username');
    $pwd = config('services.rsa.live_password');
   
    

    try {
        $yearQuery = $request->year ?? date('Y');
        $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server; database = $dbName", $uid, $pwd);
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

        // query the live db for actual value
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) as 'count', sum([RSA Balance]) as 'sum' FROM 
         RTS_TRANSFER_IN WHERE Quarter like '%" . $yearQuery . "'" . " GROUP BY Quarter");
        $stmt->execute();
        $inflows = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $stmtOutflow = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) as 'count', sum([RSA Balance]) as 'sum' 
        FROM RTS_TRANSFER_OUT WHERE Quarter like '%" . $yearQuery . "'" . " GROUP BY 
        Quarter");
        $stmtOutflow->execute();
        $outflows = $stmtOutflow->fetchAll();

        // get rts inflow and outflow targets
        $inflowTargets = Target::whereName('rts inflow')->first()->periods()->where('year', 
         $yearQuery)->get();
        $outflowTargets = Target::whereName('rts outflow')->first()->periods()->where('year', 
        $yearQuery)->get();
        
        $totalInflow = 0;
        $totalOutflow = 0;

        $totalInflowTarget = 0;
        $totalOutflowTarget = 0;
        foreach($inflows as $key => $inflow) {
            $totalInflow += $inflow['sum'];
            $totalOutflow += $outflows[$key]['sum'];
            $totalInflowTarget += $inflowTargets[$key]->value ?? 0;
            $totalOutflowTarget += $outflowTargets[$key]->value ?? 0;
        }

        return view('reports.bdm.rts', [
            'inflows' => $inflows,
            'outflows' => $outflows,
            'totalInflow' => $totalInflow,
            'totalOutflow' => $totalOutflow,
            'inflowTargets' => $inflowTargets,
            'outflowTargets' => $outflowTargets,
            'totalInflowTarget' => $totalInflowTarget,
            'totalOutflowTarget' => $totalOutflowTarget,
        ]);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the error message I am getting

ErrorException
Undefined offset: 0
http://localhost:8090/performance/reports/bdm/rts

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow dear VER, please add the line number of code that raises error. thanks

Comment: You can dump $inflows value with `dump($inflows)`, Maybe this array has no `sum` key.

Comment: Thank you @PooyaSabramooz. The array has no value on sum.